# influx aggregateWindow with continuous counter

Tags: aggregate, influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

An influx 2 database stores incrementing values from an mechanical counter (gas counter).
The goal is to build a query to get the consumption over a certain interval, e.g. one day.
With SQL I would group the data in the desired interval and than calculate max() - min()  +1 for that interval.
What is the preferred way to do that with the flux query language?

```
from(bucket: "Energy")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "gas")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["kind"] == "count")
|> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: difference, createEmpty: false)
|> yield(name: "interval")
```

does not work, error @5:6-5:69: missing required argument column (argument fn)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214037/influxdb-flux-query-with-custom-window-aggregate-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to examine difference() before aggregateWindow and as aggregate function to use sum.

```
from(bucket: "Energy")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "gas")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "count")
  |> difference()
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "consumption")
```

Comment: I think it is worth clarifying that I believe this is a work-around, not a solution to the error specifically, which has to do with an incorrect/insufficient syntax when supplying `difference` as the fn, which I think just requires explicitly defined parameters, which are often omitted because the defaults just work.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done a similar thing with an electricity counter where I wanted each window to be the difference between the last and first value of the window. Rather than taking the sum of the difference between every point in the window I used the difference between the last value of each window.

```
from(bucket: "Energy")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "gas")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["kind"] == "count")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: last)
  |> difference()
  |> yield(name: "consumption")
```